# ipython pandas table formatting

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I use `pandas` in `ipython notebook`, I get nicely formatted table:

[image]

when I use `pandas` in `ipython qtconsole`, I get an ugly table with double line border, like this:

[image]

Where can I change the look of the table, displayed in `ipython qtconsole` ?
I would like to have simple table with single border

## UPDATE:

I am using pandas version `0.8.0-2`, and the suggested option `pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)` does not exist there.

On another machine, I have tried upgrading to `0.14.1-2`, but there the table has no border at all by default (the option pd.set_option(`'display.notebook_repr_html', False)` exists, but has no effect, regardless whether I set it to `False` or `True`)

Comment: As far as I know there is no nice way of doing this without writing quite complicated code to do the table formatting. But please let me know if there is a simple answer! This is the best I've found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876022/how-to-format-ipython-html-display-of-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Probably you could use answer for that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259144/qtconsole-not-rendering-pandas-dataframes-as-html-notebook-repr-html-option)

Comment: I don't believe it is possible.  `The HTML rendering in the Qt rich text widget is pretty limited. We could embed webkit and write a fully web based UI, but that would be a major rewrite of the Qt console. We have an idea for a web console embedded in the notebook, though, so it's not impossible. – Thomas K Mar 13 '14 at 20:16`